# ffmpeg: add hyperlink to video?

Tags: ffmpeg

i am experiment with ffmpeg, making videos from more images and adding watermark, some effect etc.

What I am interested: Is it possible to embed HYPERLINK into video using ffmpeg ?

For example, watermark or something else to be 'clickable' and to redirect to some www location?

Answer (score 0):

Some video file format might support such a thing, but most don't and ffmpeg is unlikely to have support for such an esoteric feature in any case.

So no.